# Athena gives extra rows than actual present in datasource in s3

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have stored data source in s3 and when querying it in athena and querying the total no of rows , its giving me more rows than present in csv file stored in s3 .

I have also given separate path for athena query result i.e different from the data source folder path of s3 .

Please help me with this , why athena is giving me extra rows and unknown values in them ,thus creating discrepancies in the data.

Please find the query i wrote create the table in athena

```
athena_client.start_query_execution(QueryString='create database cms_data',ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://cms-dashboard-automation/Athenaoutput/'})
```

\t#Tables created for athena

```
context = {'Database': 'cms_data'}
athena_client.start_query_execution(QueryString='''CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_data`.`mpf_data` (

`State` String,
`County` String,
`Org_Name` String,
`Contract_ID` String,
`Plan_ID` double,
`Segment_ID` double,
`Plan_Type_Desc` String,
`Contract_Year` double,
`Category_Name` String,
`Service_Name` String,
`Limit_Flag` double,
`Authorization_Flag` double,
`Referral_Flag` double,
`Network_Description` String,
`Cost_Share` String )

\t ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = ',',
\t 'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://cms-dashboard-automation/MPF_Data/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
''',QueryExecutionContext = context,ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://cms-dashboard-automation/Athenaoutput/'})
```

Comment: I see you are creating a table via boto3. What is the count when you run select count(*) in Athena console ? Where do you see extra rows ?

Comment: Is the count a multitude of the expected amount? Might be that the full dataset is returned multiple times?

Comment: ¿Have you check the format and encoding of the CSV files residing in "s3://cms-dashboard-automation/MPF_Data/"?

LazySimpleSerDe does not parse correctly, for instance, quoted values with embedded endlines.